# Prevent notification when bot posts username to Slack channel

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-bolt

Is it possible to have a Slack bot post a list of usernames on a (public) channel without triggering notifications to the mentioned users? In essence, we would like the usernames/handles to be links to the users' profiles but not bother them with unnecessary notifications.

Muting the channel would not work as there are other important events that users will want to get notified of. The same applies to muting the bot.

If the bot first posts a message without the mentions and then edits that message to add the usernames, notification are not triggered. However, this seems slightly hacky but so far we have not been able to find a better way to do this. Is it somehow possible to prevent triggering the notifications when first sending the message, without going through the edit hassle?